# Keeping track of which recursive calls have been done already - C#

Tags: c#, recursion

I am solving [this problem](https://projecteuler.net/problem=15), in which I am asked for the number of shortest paths from one corner to another in a 20 by 20 grid. I know that this is an easy combinatorial problem, but the challenge for me is to implement a method that solves it.

My idea is to use recursion: The number of paths to grid point (m,n) is equal to the number of paths to (m-1,n) plus the number of paths to (m,n-1). I started out with the following code:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        long noOfPaths = CountPaths(15, 15);
        Console.WriteLine(noOfPaths);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static long CountPaths(int m, int n)
    {
        if (m == 0) return 1;
        else if (n == 0) return 1;

        return CountPaths(m-1,n) + CountPaths(m,n-1);
    }
}
```

This works very well, and returns the correct number of paths, but its run time increases dramatically as the grid size increases, and I could not get to 20x20. One of the main problems with the above is that it is making recursive calls on the same grid point more than once, and I would like some advice on the best way to keep track of this. So far, I've found posts on "global variables" around this site, and my solution is to create an array that can be accessed from anywhere. The code below solves my problem and is also rather fast.

```
using System;

namespace problem15
{
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        long noOfPaths = CountPaths(Values.m-1, Values.n-1);
        Console.WriteLine(noOfPaths);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static long CountPaths(int m, int n)
    {
        if (m == 0) return 1;
        else if (n == 0) return 1;

        if (Values.A[m - 1, n] == 0) Values.A[m - 1, n] = CountPaths(m - 1, n);
        if (Values.A[m, n - 1] == 0) Values.A[m, n - 1] = CountPaths(m, n - 1);

        return Values.A[m-1,n] + Values.A[m,n-1];
    }
}

static class Values
{
    static public int m = 21, n = 21;
    static public long[,] A = new long[m, n];
}
}
```

Is this an ok solution to the problem, or is it considered "bad form"? Also, I know that there are more optimizations in this problem, e.g. the number of paths to (k,l) is the same as the number of paths to (l,k).

Comment: the usual way to solve this is using one of the *dynamic programming* solutions (either recursion with memoization - not recommended in C#) or using tables - just google for *dynamic programming* and you will find this exact problem quickly

Comment: @Carsten thanks. From what I can tell, dynamic programming is about saving the solutions to the subproblems you have already done, and if the subproblems pop up later, you use the saved solution instead of recomputing it. In my mind, this is similar to what I did with the second solution to the problem.

Comment: This is better suited for CodeReview than StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea in your second solution is good, it's a well known technique called [Memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization). However the implementation is not. Using shared ("global") state highly limits the usage of the method, not counting the fact that the way you wrote it, it can be called only once and the parameters are hard coded. Here is the correct way of doing that.

Let start with the first solution by encapsulating it inside a class and separating the non recursive from the recursive part:

```
public class MyAlgorithms
{
    public static long CountPaths(int m, int n)
    {
        // Agrument validations goes here
        return CountPathsRecursive(m, n);
    }

    private static long CountPathsRecursive(int m, int n)
    {
        if (m == 0 || n == 0) return 1;
        var count = CountPathsRecursive(m - 1, n) + CountPathsRecursive(m, n - 1);
        return count;
    }
}
```

and use it

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        long noOfPaths = MyAlgorithms.CountPaths(21, 21);
        Console.WriteLine(noOfPaths);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Now you can optimize the **implementation** by applying the second idea **without** affecting the usage

```
public class MyAlgorithms
{
    public static long CountPaths(int m, int n)
    {
        // Agrument validations goes here
        var counts = new long[m, n];
        return CountPathsRecursive(m, n, counts);
    }

    private static long CountPathsRecursive(int m, int n, long[,] counts)
    {
        if (m == 0 || n == 0) return 1;
        var count = counts[m - 1, n - 1];
        if (count == 0) counts[m - 1, n - 1] = count =
            CountPathsRecursive(m - 1, n, counts) + CountPathsRecursive(m, n - 1, counts);
        return count;
    }
}
```

Hope you get the idea. The same way you can change the implementation to use iterative algorithm, just formula etc.

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive explanation! I believe it makes sense to me. I notice that your CountPathsRecursive method is private, while CountPaths is public. The internet says that private methods can only be called from within the class that they are defined, so the idea is that you *only* want other parts of the program to call CountPaths, because this is meant as the proper way to call CountPathsRecursive? This is confirmed, since your program refuses to let me call the MyAlgorithms.CountPathsRecursive method from Main.

Comment: Also, you pass the array "counts" to the CountPathsRecursive method. I was worried that each recursive call makes a new array that takes up space somewhere, but it seems that arrays are of something called "reference types", meaning that whatever you do to an array named "count" in subsequent recursive calls, it will be the original array that is affected. Is this correct?

Comment: @HowDoICSharply All correct :-). First is implementation specific and not supposed to be called outside. Second is reference to the array created inside the public method. It's one and the same during the method call. Like your global array, but just inside the one method call chain.

Comment: Thanks. :) It makes more sense than what I did originally, I will see if I can employ this way of thinking.

Comment: @HowDoICSharply I'm sure you will. I see the positive attitude. Or saying it the Yoda way, "No dark side I feel" :-)

Answer (score 3):

Your recursive solution is ok.

The other recursive solution is also ok and it's the recursive option to implement in the 'dynamic programming' way.

There are also an iterative and mathematical ways.

You can see more [here](http://docdro.id/oQbnNzt). It's from the official website.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun a pure OO solution (neither fast nor non-greedy ;-)  ):

There's one advantage: You get all found paths with their complete list of cells.

```
   public class MyGrid {
        public int Width { get; protected set; }
        public int Height { get; protected set; }

        public MyCell[,] MyCells { get; protected set; }

        public List<MyPath> MyPathList;

        public MyGrid(int h, int w) {
            this.Width = w;
            this.Height = h;

            this.MyCells = new MyCell[this.Width, this.Height];
            for (int x = 0; x < Width; x++) {
                for (int y = 0; y < Width; y++) {
                    this.MyCells[x, y] = new MyCell(this, x, y);
                }
            }

            this.MyPathList = new List<MyPath>();
        }

        public int FindPaths() {
            this.MyPathList.Clear();

            var p = new MyPath(this);
            this.MyPathList.Add(p);

            var c = new MyCell(this,0,0);
            p.AddCellRecursive(c); 

            return MyPathList.Count;
        }

    }
    public class MyCell {
        public MyGrid myGrid { get; protected set; }
        public int X { get; protected set; }
        public int Y { get; protected set; }
        public MyCell(MyGrid gr, int x, int y) {
            this.myGrid = gr;
            this.X = x;
            this.Y = y;
        }
        public MyCell RightNeighbour {
            get {
                if (this.X == this.myGrid.Width-1)
                    return null;
                else
                    return this.myGrid.MyCells[this.X+1, this.Y];
            }
        }
        public MyCell BelowNeighbour {
            get {
                if (this.Y == this.myGrid.Height-1)
                    return null;
                else
                    return this.myGrid.MyCells[this.X, this.Y+1];
            }
        }
        public override string ToString() {
            return string.Format("{0}|{1}", this.X, this.Y);
        }
    }
    public class MyPath{
        public MyGrid myGrid { get; protected set; }
        public List<MyCell> MyCellList;

        public MyPath(MyGrid gr) {
            this.myGrid = gr;
            this.MyCellList = new List<MyCell>(); }

        public void AddCellRecursive(MyCell c) {
            this.MyCellList.Add(c);

            var r = c.RightNeighbour;
            var b = c.BelowNeighbour;

            MyPath second=null;

            if (b == null && r == null)
                return;//end

            else if (r == null) {
                second = this;
            }
            else {
                second = this.Clone();
                this.myGrid.MyPathList.Add(second);
                this.AddCellRecursive(r);
            }

            if (b == null)
                this.myGrid.MyPathList.Remove(second);
            else 
                second.AddCellRecursive(b);

        }

        public MyPath Clone(){
            var retPath = new MyPath(this.myGrid);
            foreach (var c in MyCellList) {
                retPath.MyCellList.Add(c);
            }
            return retPath;
        }
    }
```